# Citroen jumper buss key code sign in dash

Tags: ignition, citroen

CITROËN JUMPER BUSS (230P) 2.5 TD (76 KW,1996)

I have this van, which is constantly showing orange key (code) sign in the dash.
The thing is it use to happen in last few weeks but I could get away with it doing few times lock and unlock button and then the key was accepted.
I bought this van second hand so I only have one key with a small tab for lock unlock buttons.

from last 3 days i cant make it work anymore and it seems like the key is not accepted. they light keeps there, despite resetting battery wire for hour.. bring key closer to transponder. lock unlock various times.
I dont know which thing is faulty, is it the immobilizer? the key chip or the transponder? what could be the fault.

I am a bit upset coz my van cant start anymore and i run my business through it.

Comment: I don't know much about Citroen's, but it sounds like the transponder in the vehicle has gone out. It transmits to the key, which is energized, then sends a signal back to the receiver. Unless the key is physically damaged, there usually isn't an issue with it, so leads back to the transponder. In most cases, this is a user replaceable part.

Comment: Fixed it. All I need was big hammer, break the circuit box on top of fuel pump, connect 10cm wire 12v from the circuit connector with fuel pump ignition.. there it goes.. all good now.

Comment: Please put this as your answer. Tell us why you took this approach, where you got the information to do it, and anything else which is pertinent. When you're done, select it as "the answer", which will show it as answered. :o) Great job on finding a fix and then letting us know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. Came to know that 1994-98 models for Jumper, boxer. All have immobilizer lock only on top of fuel pump. It actually blocks the 12 volts to not let the pin get magnetic and let the fuel pass through from line to pump.

All I need was big hammer, break the circuit box on top of fuel pump (its on top of the pin that blocks the fuel injection), connect 10cm wire 12v from the circuit connector with fuel pump ignition ( i took it from the circut box because 12 volts only run in it when ignition is on, you could give direct voltage from battery as well) .. there it goes.. all good now. – when ignition is turned on fuel flows into the pump !!!
There isn't any thing else as in now days fuel is blocked from tank as well.